# Proof that $f$ attains its bounds

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$: $[0, \infty)\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and such that $\lim\limits_{x\longrightarrow\infty}f(x)$ exists.

It is not hard to see that $f$ is bounded.

Unless I'm very much mistaken, $f$ also attains its bounds. What's the fastest proof of this?

Comment: A continuous functions attains its bounds on a closed and bounded interval. Here interval $[0,\infty)$ is not of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $f$ doesn't attain its bound. An easy counter-example is $$f(x)=1-\frac{1}{x+1}.$$

Comment: Right. So I am VERY much mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

The function
$$
f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R},\quad f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}
$$
is continuous and bounded between $0$ and $1$, but $f(x)\ne 0$ for every $x\in [0,\infty)$.